# Why does string sometimes is written in one direction, sometimes in another?

Tags: c++, encoding, byte-order-mark, wstring

This is code:

```
byte bytes[] = {0x2e, 0x20, 0x65, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x67, 0x00};
std::wstring s;
s.resize( 8 );
memcpy( &s[0], bytes, 16 );

_tprintf( _T("key: %s\n"), s.c_str());
MessageBox ( 0, s.c_str(), _T(""), 0 );
```

The result in message box is `gupdate` in in console `?etadpug`.

I think it is with encoding. Does 0x2e20 or 0x202e mean something?

Comment: what is your question exactly? Why _tprintf prints the inverse of MessageBox?

Comment: @Theolodis Yes, my question is why sting in message box is reversed. And in the screen is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bytes are a sequence of chars in UTF-16 (2-byte-per-char encoding).

It contains the reversed string gupdate after an RTL override mark (which reverses the order of symbols after it).

Specifically:

```
0x2e, 0x20  = U+202E = Right-To-Left override
0x65, 0x00  = U+0065 = e
0x74, 0x00  = U+0065 = t
0x61, 0x00  = U+0074 = a
etc.
```

Note how bytes are reversed.

So, the message box reverses the order of characters, because it is unicode-aware and sees the RTL override mark. Regular console output is not (actually, it is, but that depends on your project settings and the functions you use for IO. In your case it's obviously non-aware version).

Comment: I looked info about RTL and found out its mark is `0x200F` but in my case it works in this way with `202E`

Comment: 0x200F is RTL mark, 0x202E is RTL override mark. Please read the answer more carefully.

Comment: RLM (Right-to-Left Mark) affects only punctuation (i.e. exclamation mark would be on left side instead of right side), RLO (Right-to-Left override) changes the order of letters in text.